# Цикл загружает страницу php

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть файл с таким кодом

```
$result = file('base.txt');

for ($i=0; $i < 20 ; $i++) { 
$result[$i] = (int)$result[$i];
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-id&post_id='.$result[$i].'&need_likes=1&count=100')); 

for ($j=1; $j < 100 ; $j++) { 
if ($data->response[$j]->likes->count < 3){
    $cid = $data->response[$j]->cid;
    $date = $data->response[$j]->date;
    $gett = time();
    $res = $gett - $date;

    if ($res > 600){
        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.deleteComment?owner_id=-id&comment_id='.$cid.'&access_token=xxx');
    }
}
}
}
```

Ставится на крон каждые 10 мин, файл проверяет через vk api 20 последних записей в группе на наличие комментариев под этими постами с помощью цикла, запрос возвращает массив с комментариями и данными по ним, далее еще в одном цикле проходим по всем объектам комментариев и смотрим если на нем меньше 3 лайка и если ему больше 10 минут, то коментарий удаляем.

Тестил на пустой группе со своими комментами, все работало норм.
Поставил на паблик с активом, скрипт просто виснет. Даже пробую запустить вручную через адресную строку - грузит минуту две и 504 таймаут

Как я понял это из за циклов или из за чего?... Как можно оптимизировать? Надо каждый раз проверять по 2000 комментов (20 записей по 100 комментов)

Comment: а он что-нибудь вообще возвращает вам? Массив вы точно получаете?

Comment: сейчас проверил, он почему то только одну запись проверяет. загнал в массив $results 3 записи, во втором цикле сделал вывод id комментариев. по идее должны выводится id всех комментов с 3х записей, а выводятся только с первой. почему цикл останавливается, после первой итерации? там же for i=0 i<20

Comment: как я понял выполнение file_get_contents прерывает цикл for... что делать?

Comment: у вас стоит отображение ошибок?
сделайте в цикле echo "${i}<br>";